# Printing a specific page in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report with multiple pages, and when I try to print a specific page(for example I want to print page 20 in 100 page report) on the report it still prints the whole report instead of that single page. Are there any ways to achieve this?

Also when the report is exported to PDF the SSRS report do not have any blank pages in it, but when I try to print, it prints extra blank pages that are not shown in PDF.

Thank you!

Comment: Any chance you can take a screen shot of the print preview.

Answer (score 0):

For the blank pages check your margins, It may be that your content might be slightly larger than the area allowed by the margins and it spills into another page.

Report > Report Properties > Page Setup.

See if that fixes your printing problem too.

Comment: I checked the Report properties, while printing it does not show any page specific properties. I want to print single page on the report and it is not letting me do that, all the pages of that report are being printed. any ways to fix it?